# Could someone explain in detail about how that for loop works and how it looks without list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
def delete_books(name):
    books=list_book()
    books=[book for book in books if book['name']==name]
    savefile_books(books)
```

My question is about list comprehension in python. I requested you to explain in detain about this for loop. How its work and how its look in normal code without list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
books = [book for book in books if book['name']==name]
```

it is the same as:

```
new_books = []

for book in books:
  if book['name']==name:
     new_books.append(book)

books = new_books
```

As you see the list comprehension is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the same as your function, but without list comprehension:

```
def delete_books_no_list_comprehension(name):
  books = list_book()
  filtered_books = []
  for book in books:
    if book['name'] == name:
      filtered_books.append(book)
  savefile_books(filtered_books)
```

See also, for more info: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python